# How to provide an inline model field with a queryset choices without losing field value for inline records already saved

Tags: django-admin, django-forms

The code displayed below is providing the choices I need for the app field, and the choices I need for the attr field when using Admin.

I am having a problem with the attr field on the inline form for already saved records.  The attr selected for these saved does show in small print above the field, but not within the field itself.

#

MODELS:

```
Class Vocab(models.Model):  
    entity = models.Charfield, max_length = 40, unique = True)  


Class App(models.Model):  
    name = models.ForeignKey(Vocab, related_name = 'vocab_appname', unique = True)  
    app = SelfForeignKey('self, verbose_name = 'parent', blank = True, null = True)  
    attr = models.ManyToManyField(Vocab, related_name = 'vocab_appattr', through ='AppAttr'  

    def parqs(self):  

        a method that provides a queryset consisting of available apps from vocab,  
        excluding self and any apps within the current app's dependent line.  

    def attrqs(self):  

        a method that provides a queryset consisting of available attr from vocab 
        excluding those already selected by current app, 2) those already selected  
        by any apps within the current app's parent line, and 3) those selected by  
        any apps within the current app's dependent line.  

Class AppAttr(models.Model):  
    app = models.ForeignKey(App)  
    attr = models.ForeignKey(Vocab)
```

#

FORMS:

```
from models import AppAttr  

def appattr_form_callback(instance, field, *args, **kwargs)  
    if field.name = 'attr':  
        if instance:  
            return field.formfield(queryset = instance.attrqs(), **kwargs)  
    return field.formfield(**kwargs)
```

#

ADMIN:

necessary imports

```
class AppAttrInline(admin.TabularInline):  

    model = AppAttr  

    def get_formset(self, request, obj = None, **kwargs):  
        kwargs['formfield_callback'] = curry(appattr_form_callback, obj)  
        return super(AppAttrInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)  


class AppForm(forms.ModelForm):  

    class Meta:  
        model = App  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super(AppForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        if self.instance.id is None:  
            working = App.objects.all()  
        else:  
            thisrec = App.objects.get(id = self.instance.id)  
            working = thisrec.parqs()  
        self.fields['par'].queryset = working  

class AppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  

    form = AppForm  
    inlines = [AppAttrInline,]  

    fieldsets = ..........  


   necessary register statements
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha!  Just had to adjust my attrqs() query set to include, rather than exclude the attr records already selected for the current app.  It makes more sense to include those anyway.

My thanks to anyone who might have pondered this issue.